# Network created blogs URL

Tags: multisite, permalinks, url-rewriting

I'm building a blog network where people can register their blogs. As default if my domain is domain.com and if user creates a blog, the URL will be domain.com/mynewblog/

Now I would like that all blogs would be under /blogs subfolder/slug. So each time when user creates a new blog, it will be under /blogs slug, like this: domain.com/blogs/mynewblog domain.com/blogs/anotherusersblog

Propably I could achieve this my altering the htaccess file. But I'm not really comfortable with that and I have been going through the WP settings but don't find any solution for this. Is there? What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: See https://wordpress.org/support/topic/multisite-sites-in-sub-subfolders for one option.

Comment: That doesn't work perfectly because I still would like to keep my main blog/site in root. I show newest posts etc from network on main. So doing that way would be hassle.

Comment: I Googled "multinetwork" and came up with [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/). [The source](https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-multi-network/tags/1.5.1/wpmn-functions.php) indicates the existence of a `switch_to_network()` / `restore_current_network()` pairing, analogous to WP's `switch_to_blog()` / `restore_current_blog()`. I imagine you would be able to use this to get the posts from your `blogs` network. (This is one of [several multi-network plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=multi+network), too. One of the others might work better for you.)